# unable to log into a JP server on FFXIV:ARR?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I've been trying all morning to get on FFXIV. My main character is on Durandal (a legacy JP server), but I keep getting the error "Unable to update the group JP character list" when I try to go to character selection. I can see NA/EU servers just fine, but no JP servers. The realm status shows them all as being online.

Anyone know what the issue here is or how to fix it? Rebooting and multiple login/outs haven't helped.

Comment: It's been doing that with NA/EU servers, too. I had to wait 4 hours or more once, but it cleared up eventually.

Comment: It's just congestion-related, when the lobby server is overloaded and your computer can't contact it. I haven't seen it persist as long as you seem to have (for me, it usually goes away within a minute or two), but AFAIK there's nothing you can do to fix it aside from trying again.

Comment: I too have a character on the same server and have been unable to log in as said character for a fair few hours. I just started a new character on one of the NA servers for the time being, it sucks but at least I can play the game until the JP servers free up a little.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any advantage playing on JP rather than EU/NA? Would have expected some kind of region locking?

Comment: Standard MMO early release issues. You'd think the publishers would've learned by now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again later is the only thing to do.  I realize that this question was asked when login issues were rampant.  Now they are pretty rare, and usually restarting the client will fix the issue if there isn't currently ongoing maintenance.  Nothing you can do about the issue other than exit the client and try again.